# i used boolean tool on one side of the mesh but when i try to mirror the same boolean effect on the other side, mirror modifies did not work

Tags: mirror-modifier, boolean-modifier

[image: boolean modifier is used]

I tried to mirror boolean effect to the other side of the mesh, but it did not work.

Comment: Maybe put the Mirror modifier below the Boolean modifier?

Comment: pls provide blend file before (!) applying the boolean modifier. thx.

Comment: Mirror above Boolean, on the cutter, too